# Download Blob file ignores download attribute

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, download, blob

I implemented a download via blob object and when the content is bigger than 10239 characters, the download attribute is ignored and I get filenames like '*2b56fc37-9b0e-4f4c-b3f3-a28113605ea5.txt*'. Can somebody tell my why?

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/h74wca11/4/

First button creates a file with 10239 'X' and the second one a file with 10240 'X'. First button generates a file named '*test.txt*' while the second filename is arandom name like '*8cd3dc83-b3fe-4e58-99b0-39a876107a2d.txt*'

I'm using following code:

```
function myFunction(count) {
    content = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        content += 'X';
    }
    var file = new Blob([content], {
        type: 'text/plain'
    });

    var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = fileURL;
    a.target = '_blank';
    a.download = 'test.txt';
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.click();
}
```

I'm running Chrome 54.0.2840.71 m (64-bit) on Windows 10

**EDIT**
I just tried my fiddle in *incognito* modus - and it works. WTF

Comment: Seems to work OK for me, Chrome 54 on OS X Sierra. Maybe the issue is specific to your browser? If you post what OS/browsers you have tested in, maybe someone with that setup can help.

Comment: Thanks, I updated my post.

Comment: Both worked for me - Chrome 54.0.2840.71 m (64-bit) - windows 7 and also in Chrome Version 54.0.2840.87 m (64-bit) - windows 7

Comment: Maybe try something like [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js)

Comment: I just tried my fiddle in incognito modus - and it works. WTF?

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment (due my low reputation) so I will bet for a correct answer.
Try this after click():

```
a.click();
setTimeout(function(){
    document.body.removeChild(a);
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(fileURL);  
}, 100);
```

Your code works ok for me too, but sometimes you need a delay in order to work ok with blobs. I always use this and every problem (almost) with blobs goes away.
https://jsfiddle.net/h74wca11/6/